# how to extract the last inserted value

Tags: sql-server

i have two table i.e `tbl_Contactgroup(id,name)` and `tble_contactlist(id,name,address,telephoneno,mobileno,groupid)`
my question is how to retrieve all the contact list value from the `tble_contactgroup` by using extracting last inserted value from the `tbl_Contactgroup` where `id` in `tbl_Contactgroup` and `groupid` in `tble_Contactlist` are related to each other ie `foreign key`

Comment: when you say last inserted are you after only one value? also i guess your id is auto generated ID ?

Comment: yes id is autogenerated..

Comment: and you want the last Item which was inserted?

Comment: do u have any idea to retrieve all the value of tble_contactlist using tble_contactgroup

Comment: yes i want this

Comment: i use scope_identity() to retrieve identiry value but i dont still have any idea

Comment: wait a minute..what exactly are you trying? why scope_identity? are the records in both table not already inserted?

Comment: If you used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to retrieve the id of the new group row (presumably because you used it to insert all the list rows!), then all you need to do is filter the list table by that value after the rows are inserted. You don't need to do `MAX` or any of that nonsense, which, by the way, won't necessarily work correctly!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,name,address,telephoneno,mobileno 
FROM tble_contactlist 
WHERE groupid= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_Contactgroup)
```

Try this.. it will give you the data for all the value in contact list for the last inserted value in contactgroup

Comment: sir it works but what are the defference between while using scope identity() and max value

Comment: if it works brilliant..  difference is scope_identity is the valid only when you have just inserted the record.The devil is in the detail.'SCOPE'. While  max() refers to the Max value for the column which is in the case the last inserted value at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT        id,name,address,telephoneno,mobileno 
FROM          tble_contactlist 
WHERE         groupid = (SELECT  TOP(1) id FROM tbl_Contactgroup ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

Comment: this will give the top 1 in contact list.. but what he needs is the records corresponding to the last record in contact group.

Comment: @bhupendrapatel it will give last record.. `ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: you are thinking last record in contactlist.. its last record in contact group.

Comment: Thanx @bhupendrapatel, now it will work..

Comment: thank you so much bhupendrapatel sir and Shahid Iqbal sir Both code working well but currenlty i am using bhupendra sir code thank you once again stay in touch..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other SQL Select statement that can help
This differs with [aggregate function used with Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) (like MAX(), SUM(), COUNT(), etc)

```
select
*
from tble_contactlist 
where id in (
    select
        max(id) over (partition by groupid) 
    from tble_contactlist
)
```

Another solution can be as follows

```
;with cte as (
select
    c.*, max(c.id) over (partition by g.id) mid
from tbl_Contactgroup g
inner join tble_contactlist c on g.id = c.groupid
)
select * from cte where id = mid
```